# Angular SSR 'Failed to lookup view' on production (Ubuntu, Nginx)

Tags: angular, express, nginx, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

Following up the official Angular tutorial on setting up SSR using Express server:
https://angular.io/guide/universal#configure-for-universal

The tutorial would setup paths like this:

```
...
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
...
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));
```

This works pretty well on the local server.

However once deployed at the server (powered by Nginx), getting the error:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory
>   "/home/user_name/dist/browser"
>       at Function.render (/var/proj_name/server.js:44670:17)
>       at ServerResponse.render (/var/proj_name/server.js:53701:7)
>       at /var/proj_name/server.js:121:9
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/proj_name/server.js:46582:5)
>       at next (/var/proj_name/server.js:46330:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (/var/proj_name/server.js:46305:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/proj_name/server.js:46582:5)
>       at /var/proj_name/server.js:45805:22
>       at param (/var/proj_name/server.js:45878:14)
>       at param (/var/proj_name/server.js:45889:14)

How to handle this correctly so the app works properly both locally (for development) and on the production server?

**EDIT:**

Have also tried to use `__dirname` instead:

app.get('*.*', express.static(join(__dirname, 'browser')));

But this fails both locally and on production server:

> Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/browser"

**EDIT2:**

I have managed to make this work by moving `browser` folder into `~/dist/browser`. But I don't want the app to work this way.

Looks like the failing code is in *server.ts*:

```
// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});
```

When ran locally, the `const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');` returns correct output. However when ran on the real server (Ubuntu, Nginx) it gets: `/home/<user_name>/dist/browser` instead. Using `__dirname` didn't help.

So need some way to make sure `res.render('index', { req });` gets the correct resource.

Comment: What's the `browser` directory full path when served via nginx?

Comment: @David it is: _/var/<project_name>/browser_. Adding EDIT2 for some more findings.

Comment: Do you run 2 separate node instances? One for dev and one for testing with nginx? If so and if you want to use `process.cwd` you should run node from `/var/<project_name>/browser.`

Comment: Locally I ran the same setup as in the article: https://angular.io/guide/universal#configure-for-universal. On the remote server (VPS provided by the hosting company) I run the app in _localhost:4000_ and then use Nginx `proxy_pass` and serve the app for the website users.

Comment: But where do you start the node process from on your VPS?

Comment: The node process is started using PM2, e.g. `pm2 start server`. Calling pm2 from the user folder e.g. `~`. Hmm, I will try to run the app directly (seems like pm2 might change cwd - leading to the problem).

Comment: You need to start that pm2 command from your projet root... otherwise `process.cwd` will resolve to `~` (or `/home/username`)

Comment: That would resolve the issue @David. Feel free to add the answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the following piece of code

```
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));
```

means that the view engine will look for views in this directory:  `<currentWorkingDirectory>/dist/browser`

The current working directory corresponds to the directory where the node process was started from.

So if you want your code to work the same way for local and prod environment (using nginx), you need to make sure that the directory where you start node from is always the parent directory of the `dist/browser` directory

So you should run node (or pm2) from `/var/<project_name>/`

Comment: But there is no folder named `browser`?