# Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/root/client/dist/dist/browser"

Tags: angular

after I run my Angular 7 Universal application I am getting an error

***Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/root/client/dist/dist/browser"***

The problem seems to be on the client site.

I have installed the packages and build the application again the application is running but if I start the browser then I am getting the error.

> > Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/root/client/dist/dist/browser" at Function.render(/root/client /
> >     dist / server.js: 49345: 17) at ServerResponse.render(/root/client /
> >     dist / server.js: 58250: 7) at / root / client / dist / server.js:
> >     138: 9 at Layer.handle[as handle_request](/root/client / dist /
> >     server.js: 51131: 5) at next(/root/client / dist / server.js: 50879:
> >     13) at Route.dispatch(/root/client / dist / server.js: 50854: 3) at
> >     Layer.handle[as handle_request](/root/client / dist / server.js:
> >     51131: 5) at / root / client / dist / server.js: 50354: 22 at
> >     param(/root/client / dist / server.js: 50427: 14) at
> >     param(/root/client / dist / server.js: 50438: 14)

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import {
    enableProdMode
} from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import {
    join
} from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

declare var window;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4200;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {
    AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    LAZY_MODULE_MAP
} = require('./dist/server/main');

// Express Engine
import {
    ngExpressEngine
} from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import {
    provideModuleMap
} from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';



app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
        provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// TODO: implement data requests securely
app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
});

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {
        req
    });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

**SOLUTION**
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52310607/angular-ssr-failed-to-lookup-view-on-production-ubuntu-nginx)